# How to create a dataframe from just parts of a JSON?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

In Python 3 I have a program for accessing a API of Brazilian Senators Bill's. I intend to read in JSON and then transform into a dataframe in pandas. I did so:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {"Accept" : "application/json"}

proposals = []
url = 'http://legis.senado.leg.br/dadosabertos/materia/pesquisa/lista?ano=2010'

try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc) 
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)  
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("OOps: Something Else",err)

content = r.json()

for item in content["PesquisaBasicaMateria"]["Materias"]["Materia"]:
    dicionario = {"AnoMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['AnoMateria']), 
                      "CodigoMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['CodigoMateria']), 
                      "DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria'], 
                      "DescricaoObjetivoProcesso": item["DescricaoObjetivoProcesso"] if "DescricaoObjetivoProcesso" in item else None,
                      "DescricaoSubtipoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['DescricaoSubtipoMateria'], 
                      "IndicadorTramitando": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['IndicadorTramitando'], 
                      "NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria": item['IdentificacaoMateria']['NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria'], 
                      "NumeroMateria": str(item['IdentificacaoMateria']['NumeroMateria']), 
                      "ApelidoMateria": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['ApelidoMateria'] if 'ApelidoMateria' in item else None, 
                      "DataApresentacao": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['DataApresentacao'], 
                      "DataLeitura": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['DataLeitura'] if 'DataLeitura' in item else None,
                      "EmentaMateria": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['EmentaMateria'] if 'EmentaMateria' in item else None,
                      "ExplicacaoEmentaMateria": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['ExplicacaoEmentaMateria'] if 'ExplicacaoEmentaMateria' in item else None,
                      "IndicadorComplementar": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['IndicadorComplementar'] if 'IndicadorComplementar' in item else None,
                      "NaturezaMateria": item['DadosBasicosMateria']['NaturezaMateria'] if 'NaturezaMateria' in item else None,
                      "NomeAutor": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['NomeAutor'] if 'NomeAutor' in item else None,
                      "SiglaTipoAutor": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['SiglaTipoAutor'] if 'SiglaTipoAutor' in item else None,
                      "IndicadorOutrosAutores": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['IndicadorOutrosAutores'] if 'IndicadorOutrosAutores' in item else None,
                      "CodigoParlamentar": str(item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['IdentificacaoParlamentar']['CodigoParlamentar']) if 'CodigoParlamentar' in item else None,
                      "NomeParlamentar": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['IdentificacaoParlamentar']['NomeParlamentar'] if 'NomeParlamentar' in item else None,
                      "NomeCompletoParlamentar": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['IdentificacaoParlamentar']['NomeCompletoParlamentar'] if 'NomeCompletoParlamentar' in item else None,
                      "UrlFotoParlamentar": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['IdentificacaoParlamentar']['UrlFotoParlamentar'] if 'UrlFotoParlamentar' in item else None,
                      "UfParlamentar": item['AutoresPrincipais']['AutorPrincipal']['IdentificacaoParlamentar']['UfParlamentar'] if 'UfParlamentar' in item else None,
                      "DataSituacao": item['SituacaoAtual']['Autuacoes']['Autuacao']['Situacao']['DataSituacao'] if 'DataSituacao' in item else None,
                      "DescricaoSituacao": item['SituacaoAtual']['Autuacoes']['Autuacao']['Situacao']['DescricaoSituacao'] if 'DescricaoSituacao' in item else None
                      }
    proposals.append(dicionario)

df_projetos_api = pd.DataFrame(proposals)
df_projetos_api.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4216 entries, 0 to 4215
Data columns (total 25 columns):
AnoMateria                       4216 non-null object
ApelidoMateria                   0 non-null object
CodigoMateria                    4216 non-null object
CodigoParlamentar                0 non-null object
DataApresentacao                 4216 non-null object
DataLeitura                      0 non-null object
DataSituacao                     0 non-null object
DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria    4216 non-null object
DescricaoObjetivoProcesso        0 non-null object
DescricaoSituacao                0 non-null object
DescricaoSubtipoMateria          4216 non-null object
EmentaMateria                    0 non-null object
ExplicacaoEmentaMateria          0 non-null object
IndicadorComplementar            0 non-null object
IndicadorOutrosAutores           0 non-null object
IndicadorTramitando              4216 non-null object
NaturezaMateria                  0 non-null object
NomeAutor                        0 non-null object
NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria     4216 non-null object
NomeCompletoParlamentar          0 non-null object
NomeParlamentar                  0 non-null object
NumeroMateria                    4216 non-null object
SiglaTipoAutor                   0 non-null object
UfParlamentar                    0 non-null object
UrlFotoParlamentar               0 non-null object
dtypes: object(25)
memory usage: 411.8+ KB
```

This worked but I had two problems that I realized later:

1 - Dataframes "AutoresPrincipais_df " and "SituacaoAtual_df" have sublayers, varying the amount of keys/columns

Examples:

```
'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Eunício Oliveira',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'SENADOR',
       'UfAutor': 'CE',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não',
       'IdentificacaoParlamentar': {'CodigoParlamentar': '612',
        'NomeParlamentar': 'Eunício Oliveira',
        'NomeCompletoParlamentar': 'Eunício Lopes de Oliveira',
        'SexoParlamentar': 'Masculino',
        'FormaTratamento': 'Senador',
        'UrlFotoParlamentar': 'http://www.senado.leg.br/senadores/img/fotos-oficiais/senador612.jpg',
        'UrlPaginaParlamentar': 'http://www25.senado.leg.br/web/senadores/senador/-/perfil/612',
        'SiglaPartidoParlamentar': 'MDB',
        'UfParlamentar': 'CE'}}},
```

or

```
'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Ministério da Fazenda',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'MINISTERIO',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}},
```

Examples of SituacaoAtual_df

```
'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-06-28',
         'CodigoSituacao': '107',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'CONHECIDA',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'CONHECIDA.'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-06-28',
         'CodigoLocal': '438',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'COARQ',
         'NomeLocal': 'Coordenação de Arquivo'}}}}},
```

or

```
'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-06-06',
         'CodigoSituacao': '25',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'APRVD',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'APROVADA'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-06-07',
         'CodigoLocal': '440',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'SEXPE',
         'NomeLocal': 'Secretaria de Expediente'}}}}},
```

2 - The four dataframes do not have a single key to merge later. This means that I have to create the dataframe in order of appearance of the "IdentificacaoMateria", "DadosBasicosMateria", "AutoresPrincipais" and "SituacaoAtual" groups. Each group of this within JSON is a line in the dataframe

Here is an excerpt from the initial lines of JSON

```
{'PesquisaBasicaMateria': {'@xmlns:xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
  '@xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation': 'http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/dados/PesquisaBasicaMateriav5.xsd',
  'Metadados': {'Versao': '16/01/2019 12:38:14',
   'VersaoServico': '5',
   'DataVersaoServico': '2017-02-01',
   'DescricaoDataSet': 'Efetua a pesquisa de matérias, com a criação de um filtro através dos parâmetros que podem ser informados.\n      Se não informar parâmetro algum, não retorna conteúdo.'},
  'Materias': {'Materia': [{'IdentificacaoMateria': {'CodigoMateria': '132317',
      'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF',
      'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal',
      'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'ACE',
      'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'AVISO DA COMISSÃO DE EDUCAÇÃO',
      'NumeroMateria': '00001',
      'AnoMateria': '2018',
      'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'ACE 1/2018',
      'IndicadorTramitando': 'Não'},
     'DadosBasicosMateria': {'EmentaMateria': 'Avalia as medidas adotadas pelo Governo Federal e pelas prefeituras municipais para implementar as estratégias do Plano Nacional de Educação no que concerne à sua Meta 1 (educação infantil), bem como as medidas adotadas pelos entes federativos para promover o funcionamento de creches e pré-escolas construídas com recursos federais por meio do Proinfância.',
      'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não',
      'DataApresentacao': '2018-02-23',
      'NaturezaMateria': {'CodigoNatureza': '304',
       'NomeNatureza': 'DECISAO_TCU',
       'DescricaoNatureza': 'Decisão do Tribunal de Contas da União'}},
     'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Tribunal de Contas da União',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'TRIBUNAL_CONTAS_UNIAO',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}},
     'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-03-07',
         'CodigoSituacao': '107',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'CONHECIDA',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'CONHECIDA.'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-03-07',
         'CodigoLocal': '47',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'CE',
         'NomeLocal': 'Comissão de Educação, Cultura e Esporte'}}}}},
    {'IdentificacaoMateria': {'CodigoMateria': '133324',
      'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF',
      'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal',
      'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'ACE',
      'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'AVISO DA COMISSÃO DE EDUCAÇÃO',
      'NumeroMateria': '00002',
      'AnoMateria': '2018',
      'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'ACE 2/2018',
      'IndicadorTramitando': 'Não'},
     'DadosBasicosMateria': {'EmentaMateria': 'Analisa a regularidade do usufruto da isenção de contribuição para a seguridade social das entidades beneficentes de assistência social, com atuação preponderante na área de educação.',
      'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não',
      'DataApresentacao': '2018-05-18',
      'NaturezaMateria': {'CodigoNatureza': '304',
       'NomeNatureza': 'DECISAO_TCU',
       'DescricaoNatureza': 'Decisão do Tribunal de Contas da União'}},
     'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Tribunal de Contas da União',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'TRIBUNAL_CONTAS_UNIAO',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}},
     'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-07-10',
         'CodigoSituacao': '107',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'CONHECIDA',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'CONHECIDA.'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-07-10',
         'CodigoLocal': '47',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'CE',
         'NomeLocal': 'Comissão de Educação, Cultura e Esporte'}}}}},
    {'IdentificacaoMateria': {'CodigoMateria': '133655',
      'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'SF',
      'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria': 'Senado Federal',
      'SiglaSubtipoMateria': 'ACE',
      'DescricaoSubtipoMateria': 'AVISO DA COMISSÃO DE EDUCAÇÃO',
      'NumeroMateria': '00003',
      'AnoMateria': '2018',
      'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria': 'ACE 3/2018',
      'IndicadorTramitando': 'Não'},
     'DadosBasicosMateria': {'EmentaMateria': 'Avalia a atuação do Ministério da Educação nos processos de regulação, supervisão e avaliação da educação superior, tendo como uma de suas referências a estratégia 12.19 do Plano Nacional de Educação.',
      'IndicadorComplementar': 'Não',
      'DataApresentacao': '2018-06-14',
      'NaturezaMateria': {'CodigoNatureza': '304',
       'NomeNatureza': 'DECISAO_TCU',
       'DescricaoNatureza': 'Decisão do Tribunal de Contas da União'}},
     'AutoresPrincipais': {'AutorPrincipal': {'NomeAutor': 'Tribunal de Contas da União',
       'SiglaTipoAutor': 'TRIBUNAL_CONTAS_UNIAO',
       'IndicadorOutrosAutores': 'Não'}},
     'SituacaoAtual': {'Autuacoes': {'Autuacao': {'NumeroAutuacao': '1',
        'Situacao': {'DataSituacao': '2018-12-21',
         'CodigoSituacao': '28',
         'SiglaSituacao': 'ARQVD',
         'DescricaoSituacao': 'ARQUIVADA AO FINAL DA LEGISLATURA'},
        'Local': {'DataLocal': '2018-12-21',
         'CodigoLocal': '438',
         'SiglaCasaLocal': 'SF',
         'NomeCasaLocal': 'Senado Federal',
         'SiglaLocal': 'COARQ',
         'NomeLocal': 'Coordenação de Arquivo'}}}}},
```

...

Then within Materia the keys "IdentificacaoMateria", "DadosBasicosMateria", "AutoresPrincipais" and "SituacaoAtual" are repeated, each repetition being a dataframe line

So I want to create a dataframe in which each row is formed by the columns that are in "IdentificacaoMateria", "DadosBasicosMateria", "AutoresPrincipais" and "SituacaoAtual", with its contents

Please, is it possible to create a dataframe from a JSON document so as to just select some internal keys?

The way I did, with the help of various information from colleagues, worked. But you can see that some columns were completely empty. I did not understand why, since I did not indicate the full path until the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two levels to the json. The first is "PesquisaBasicaMateria". So to get the dictionary you want, you use:

```
mats = projects['PesquisaBasicaMateria']['Materias']
```

And then look at or get each "Materia" from `mats`.

```
materia = mats['Materia']
```

That is a list you have to unpack even further.

```
dict_l = [d['IdentificacaoMateria'] for d in mat]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_l)
```

This gives you a DataFrame of 10 columns and five rows. The columns are:

`['AnoMateria', 'CodigoMateria', 'DescricaoIdentificacaoMateria', 'DescricaoObjetivoProcesso', 'DescricaoSubtipoMateria', 'IndicadorTramitando', 'NomeCasaIdentificacaoMateria', 'NumeroMateria', 'SiglaCasaIdentificacaoMateria', 'SiglaSubtipoMateria']`

Comment: Thank you very much. The generated dataframe has the columns: "IdentificacaoMateria", "DadosBasicosMateria", "AutoresPrincipais" and "SituacaoAtual". Each column has a set of dictionaries inside. I would like the final dataframe to have the columns of all these dictionaries

Comment: I tried: dados_b = mats['Materia']['DadosBasicosMateria']

Comment: To do a test and maybe join the four dataframes later, but this error appeared: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Please, have you any idea how I can do a final dataframe with all the dictionaries and their columns?

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I have not had success yet. I put up the new code I made and the problems I discovered. Is almost working

Comment: Could you work with multiple dataframes or are you trying to create a superset of all the possible columns with a sparsely populated DataFrame?

Comment: I want to create a unique dataframe. It is not recommended to create separate dataframes because there is no single key that connects them. What binds the information in the JSON is the order of the key sets

Comment: Your original question has been solved. The solution proposed here worked. You have a new question. You can't keep editing the same question with new questions until your project is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can just access that key and build the dataframe from there:

```
projects = r.json()

mats = projects.get('Materias') # This is a dictionary

if not mats:
    raise ValueError("Didn't find anything in 'Materias')

mats_list = mats.get('Materia') # This should be a list of dictionaries

if not mats_list:
    raise ValueError("Got None or empty list in 'Materia'")

df = pd.DataFrame(mats_list)
```

This is assuming the json structure looks like:

```
{ 'Materias': {
     'Materia': [ # interesting dictionaries]
    }
}
```

If the nesting goes down further like it appears to, this might be a bit more tricky

Comment: Thank you very much. But the 'mats' are empty.

Comment: mats = projects.get('Materias')

Comment: mats - is without content

Answer (score 1):

Digging thru the JSON response to Materia we find a list:

```
the_json["PesquisaBasicaMateria"]["Materias"]["Materia"]
```

The sample tested contained `3014 items` each being a dictionary themselves with anywhere between 2-4 of the following keys:

```
['IdentificacaoMateria', 'DadosBasicosMateria', 'AutoresPrincipais', 'SituacaoAtual']
['IdentificacaoMateria', 'DadosBasicosMateria', 'AutoresPrincipais']
['IdentificacaoMateria', 'DadosBasicosMateria', 'SituacaoAtual']
['IdentificacaoMateria', 'DadosBasicosMateria']
```

Each of these 4 types contain unique fields, without knowing more about the data or your desire it is difficult to project how you'd like this data combined in a single recordset.

However, you could start by having a look at the 4 types of Materia in their own respective DataFrames like this:

```
the_records = {
    "IdentificacaoMateria": [],
    "DadosBasicosMateria":  [],
    "AutoresPrincipais":    [],
    "SituacaoAtual":        []
}
for item in the_json["PesquisaBasicaMateria"]["Materias"]["Materia"]:
    for subkey in item.keys():
        the_records[subkey].append(item[subkey])

IdentificacaoMateria_df = pd.DataFrame(the_records["IdentificacaoMateria"])
DadosBasicosMateria_df  = pd.DataFrame(the_records["DadosBasicosMateria"])
AutoresPrincipais_df    = pd.DataFrame(the_records["AutoresPrincipais"])
SituacaoAtual_df        = pd.DataFrame(the_records["SituacaoAtual"])
```

Then maybe have a look at:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html
and experiment with `pd.concat` to combine the records in the way you are after.

Comment: Thank you very much. But unfortunately these data are more complex than I thought. AutoresPrincipais_df and SituacaoAtual_df have sublayers inside

Comment: I'll put a more detailed description in the question

Comment: I have already put the changes in the question that show more details of the JSON. Thank you